# How to Query cell reference, with partial match of the data in the referenced cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Trying to run a query that will auto-populate cells by partially matching cell I2, the problem is if I2 says "Paris, France". and the data range only has "Paris", the query returns no results.

I have tested and confirmed that it's the extra text in I2 that tells the query there's no match. Even if there are valid partial matches.

```
=query(main!C1:S,"SELECT S WHERE C LIKE '"&I2&"'",0)
```

I believe the solution lies in adding a wildcard, but I don't know how to do it when there's a cell reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `contains` instead:

```
=QUERY(main!C1:S, "select S where C contains '"&I2&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

the other way around would be:

```
=QUERY(main!C1:S, "select S where C contains '"&SPLIT(I2, ",")&"'", 0)
```

---

```
=QUERY(main!C1:S, "select S where C starts with '"&SPLIT(I2, ",")&"'", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. The main issue is that i2 has more data than the lookup. Starts with is a great alternative, but suffers from the same problem.
I guess it's unavoidable to do something with SPLIT.  

Even though it's not what I wanted, it is the correct solution to the problem. Thank you player0!